# How do I re-use a vector from a dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, vector

I am trying to re-use vectors from a dictionary, but Python modifies the dictionary even if I pull the vector and rename it.  Any ideas around this problem.  Here's my code:

```
# Set up dictionary

d = {'id 1':[20,15,30]}
d['id 2'] = [5,10,50]

# Pull a vector from the dictionary and decrease the first entry in the vector

vector = d['id 2']
vector[0] = vector[0] - 1
print vector

# Pull the same vector from the dictionary (This is where I want the original vector)

vector2 = d['id 2']
vector2[0] = vector2[0] - 1 
print vector2
```

When I

```
print vector
# => [4, 10, 50]
```

When I

```
print vector2
# => [3, 10, 50]
```

Why doesn't it reassign `vector2` to the original `[5,10,50]` `vector`?  I want both of these to give me `[4,10,50]`, but the second one gives me `[3,10,50]`.

Answer (score 2):

Make a copy or deep copy of the list.

```
In [34]: d = {'id 1':[20,15,30]}

In [35]: d['id 2'] = [5,10,50]

In [36]: vector = d['id 2'][:]

In [37]: vector[0] = vector[0] - 1

In [38]: print vector
[4, 10, 50]

In [39]: vector2 = d['id 2'][:]

In [40]: vector2[0] = vector2[0] - 1

In [41]: print vector2
[4, 10, 50]
```

Lists are mutable, so when you initially do `vector[0] = vector[0] - 1`, you change the list in place (as `vector2 = d['id 2']` gets a reference to the original list), so when you do `vector2 = d['id 2']`, you get the changed vector instead of the original one.

P.S - `lst[:]` makes a shallow copy, use `copy.deepcopy(lst)` for deep copying a list.

Answer (score 1):

When you assign the *list* to the variable `vector`, you're not actually copying the list, you're only getting a reference to it. If you want a copy you have to explicitly copy it using e.g. the slice-operator:

```
vector = d['id 2'][:]
```